# Geo distance filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I am receiving a 400 bad request error from elasticsearch. The error is a big block response but I believe this is the key part.

```
failed to find mapper for [location] for geo distance based sort
```

I am using ES 1.5.1 to query to. My query is:

```
{
  query: {
    filtered: {
      query: {
        match: {
          title:"amsterdam*"
        }
      }
    }
  }, sort: [
       {
         _geo_distance: {
           location: {lat:0, lon:0}, order:"asc", unit:"miles"
         }
       }
     ]
}
```

I have formatted the query just like the documentation [here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/sorting-by-distance.html). Am I missing a step?

This is my current mapping:

```
{
  "gb": {
    "mappings": {
      "store": {
        "dynamic":"false",
        "properties": {
          "active": {
            "type": "b‌​oolean"
          },
          "deleted": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "location": {
            "type":"geo_point"
          },
          "open": {
            "ty‌​pe": "boolean"
          },
          "suspended": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "title": {
            "type":"string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: May you share mapping?

Comment: I'm relatively new to ES. How do I share mapping? I can read the documentation and try to figure it out.

Comment: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html - basically type http://localhost:9200/index name/_mapping into browser and post received Json

Comment: This is what I get.

    `{"gb":{"mappings":{"store":{"dynamic":"false","properties":{"active":{"type":"boolean"},"deleted":{"type":"boolean"},"location":{"type":"geo_point"},"open":{"type":"boolean"},"suspended":{"type":"boolean"},"title":{"type":"string"}}}}}}`

Comment: It all looks fine, including your mapping. How do you issue the query?

Comment: @jkbkot I am using a ruby backend. It's pretty complex but basically I am using Elasticsearch::Model. I have a stores table in my db. I am searching using this line `Store.__elasticsearch__.search(query)`

Comment: are you sure you're setting the correct index (`gb`) and type(`store`)?

Comment: @jkbkot I'm definitely sure it's correct. I'm trying to fix this without having to recreate the mapping. But it looks like I might have to.

Comment: well, it simply looks like `location` is not of type `geo_point` which would mean that the mapping is wrong, which it seems it's not, or that you're querying the wrong index. Or the ruby library mangles your query. You could try to intercept the call. E.g. `sudo tcpflow -i any -C -J port 9300` on linux, or `sudo tcpflow -i lo0 -C -J port 9300` on a mac. 9200 if you're using the the HTTP REST endpoint.

Comment: @jkbkot I intercepted the call. It hit the end point but it's still complaining about the location mapping error (and returns 400). The strange part is that this is passing with my rspec. Yet, when I use Postman, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine. The field `location` must have the mapping type `geo_point`, which it seems it has.

Try this Marvel Sense script:

(install Marvel by running `bin/plugin -i elasticsearch/marvel/latest`)

```
put geo
put geo/geo/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "location": {
          "type": "geo_point",
          "geohash" : true
    }
  }
}
put geo/geo/1
{
  "location": {
    "lat": 0.1,
    "lon": 0.1
  }
}
put geo/geo/2
{
  "location": {
    "lat": 50.1,
    "lon": 7.1
  }
}
put geo/geo/3
{
  "location": {
    "lat": 5.1,
    "lon": 3.1
  }
}
get geo/geo/_search
{
  "query": {
        "match_all": {
        }
    }, 
  "sort": [
       {
         "_geo_distance": {
           "location": {"lat":0, "lon":0}, 
           "order":"asc", 
           "unit":"km"
         }
       }
     ]
}
get geo/_mapping
```

For some reason, the search query doesn't work for me from Sense. Via curl it works without problems though:

`curl -XGET '0:9200/geo/geo/_search?pretty' -d@query.json`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error using the elasticsearch npm - I don't think the mapping was getting created correctly.  I had to format my geopoint type as an array to get everything working.

Using an object type did not work

```
"location": { 
    "lat": 41.12,
    "lon": -71.34
 }
```

Format your field as an array instead

```
"location": [ -71.34, 41.12 ]
```